# How to detect user is idle or inactivity in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Suppose I have an action to be executed after a certain amount of time without the user touching the screen. How can I implement a timer that executes an action when it times out, but starts over user trigger a switch

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use LaunchedEffect:

```
LaunchedEffect(key = <your switch state>) {
   delay(<certain amount of time in milliseconds>)
   executeAction() // action to be executed
}
```

`LaunchedEffect` restarts its lambda when key changes. So this code will call `executeAction()` after specified delay only if the key remains the same. If User toggles Switch, its state changes and `LaunchedEffect` restarts and `delay()` will be called again.

Comment: ? please more spesific bro

Comment: @Taka Nendra Han See updated answer

Comment: A link to documentation would be nice here :)